# check a date between two dates - PHP

Tags: php, date, compare

I want to check a certain date that is stored in my DB, if this date is during this fiscal year it prints **valid** if it is not it prints **invalid**

here is my php code:

```
$init_date= date("2016/07/01");
$end_date= date("2017/06/30");
$i_date = strtotime($init_date);
$e_date = strtotime($end_date);
$date_db= strtotime($date);// this $date is retrieved from my DB
if ($e_date > $date_db && $i_date < $date_db) 
     { echo "valid";}
else { echo "invalid";}
```

but the problem is that i don't want to set the start and the end dates manually, is there a way to make it dynamic? as it will be updated every year

Comment: "is there a way to make it dynamic?" - yes, just tell us, what is the rule for dates generation.

Comment: I dont understand if all the dates are in Date format than why `strtotime`?

Comment: @user4035 sorry I didn't get your question, what do you mean by date generation?

Comment: @Smit i did it based on this example [link](http://www.highlystructured.com/comparing_dates_php.html), I understood it is easier in this way but if there is a better way please tell me

Comment: @Rawabi.a You said: "i don't want to set the start and the end dates manually" - so, you want a computer to generate these dates. How should they be generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way your script will be a bit more ***dynamic***.

```
// the below snippet checks the date retrieved from database
// against fiscal periods between years 2000 and 2050 and return the 
// valid dates
$endYear=2000;
while($endYear<=2050) {
$end = $endYear.'/06/30';
$endDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', $end);
$initDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', $end);
$initDate = $initDate->sub(new DateInterval('P1Y'))->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
$ddb = '2016-09-27';
$dateFrodDB = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $ddb);
if ($dateFrodDB>=$initDate && $dateFrodDB<=$endDate) 
     { echo "valid\n";
         echo "\tStartDate->\"".$initDate->format("Y-m-d")."\"\n";
         echo "\tEndDate->\"".$endDate->format("Y-m-d")."\"\n";
         echo "\tDateFromDatabase->\"".$dateFrodDB->format("Y-m-d")."\"\n";
     }
$endYear++;
}

/* output
   valid
        StartDate->"2016-07-01"
        EndDate->"2017-06-30"
        DateFromDatabase->"2016-09-27"
*/
```

check this on [PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/277fa9910e419b9b843872fdeffff668fb15d40b)

Comment: thank you so much, i just have a question about how `$endYear++` will increment per year? or how does it work?

Comment: @Rawabi.a `$endYEar` is in a `while` loop meaning that it will check all dates for 50 years from 2000 to 2050 if you want just change those numbers

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?php
$start_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace("/", "-", $initdate)));
$end_date   = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace("/", "-", $end_date)));
$new_date   = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace("/", "-", $date)));
 if (($start_date < $new_date && $new_date < $end_date) || ($end_date < $new_date && $new_date < $start_date)) {
    echo "valid";
} else {
    echo 'invalid';
}
```

Here is working [link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b75343bfc2806d94f3fcab8b66d75534f85e8c97)

Comment: it shows **invalid**, even though the retrieved date is between these 2 dates

Comment: it worked thanks, but in this case you set the start and the end by yourself so it is no longer dynamic, right?

Comment: OKay, I got you. Hang on, I will be ready with dynamic nature

Comment: I updated condition, it will work, in both cases now. Means even if your start date and end date will exchange itself, above code will work. I updated link too

Comment: When calculating with dates in PHP It's better to use the date time object. That way everything related to times, zones, etcetera is handled for you. Makes life easier

Comment: Thanks for suggestion ! But I am writing this code on the behalf of raw date or data. I think you got my point.

Comment: Your most welcome ! If your problem has been solved by my answer, you can accept my answer and upvote it